# SSIS reading LF as terminator when its set as CRLF

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, flat-file

using SSIS 2012. My flat file connection manager I have a delimited file where the row delimiter is set to `CRLF`, but when it processes the file, I have a text column that has an `LF` in it. This is causing it to read that as a row terminator causing it fail. Any ideas?

Comment: i was mis-understanding your question. i was thinking that your flat file contains multiple row delimiter. i edited my answer take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank u for all the suggestions. turned out that the vendor had changed the encoding of the file from Ascii to unicode. changing the the package to read the correct encoding did the trick.

Comment: Just accept this answer even if it yours, so the question is marked as answered. Also the answers provided are helpful and these people spend there times to solve your issue so it is nice to up vote there answers

Answer (score 2):

*Before answering, i don't think that the column contains only `LF` because if the row delimiter is `CRLF` it will not consider it as delimiter. So it is probably `CRLF`, but i will give a solution for the two cases (CRLF or LF)*

### Solution

You can fix this situation with the following steps:

1. First in the Flat File connection manager add only one column (of type `DT_STR` and length `4000`) so you will consider each row as one column.
2. In the data flow task you have to add a Script component that fix the file structure. and split row into columns.

### Simple Test

I will consider a flat file with the following content

```
ID;name;DOB;Notes;ClassID{CRLF}
1;John;2001-01-01;;1{CRLF}
2;Moh;2002-01-01;Very cool{LF}
Genius;2{CRLF}
3;Ali;2000-01-01;Calm;2{CRLF}
```

1. First i will add a flat file connection manager with the following options:

   - Row Delimiter = {CRLF}
   - Header Row Delimiter = {CRLF}

[image]

2. In the DataFlow Task i will add a `Flat File Source`, 2 x `Script Component` , `OLEDB Destination`
3. In the first Script Component i will mark `Column0` as input and i will add 5 output Columns `ID,Name,DOB,Notes,ClassID` and i will set the Output Synchronous Input as `None`

[image]

4. In the first Script Component i will write a script that store each line in a memory variable and assign it to an output row when row is complete and another row is present.

   ```
   Dim strLine As String = String.Empty

   Dim strDelimiter As String = ";"

   Public Sub EmptyMemoryVariables()


       strLine = String.Empty


   End Sub

   Public Sub AssignMemoryVariablesToOutput()

       With Output0Buffer

           .AddRow()
           .NewRow = strLine
       End With

   End Sub

   Public Function AreVariablesEmpty() As Boolean

       If strLine = "" Then

           Return True

       Else

           Return False

       End If


   End Function
   Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

       Dim strColumns As String() = Row.Column0.Split(CChar(strDelimiter))

       If strColumns.Length = 5 Then

           If Not AreVariablesEmpty() Then
               AssignMemoryVariablesToOutput()
               EmptyMemoryVariables()
           End If

           strLine = Row.Column0

           AssignMemoryVariablesToOutput()
           EmptyMemoryVariables()


       Else

           If strLine.Split(CChar(strDelimiter)).Length = 5 Then

               AssignMemoryVariablesToOutput()
               EmptyMemoryVariables()

           End If


           strLine &= Row.Column0







       End If
   ```
5. In the second Script COmponent i will split each row into Columns

[image]

```
    Dim strDelimiter As String = ";"
    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

        Dim strColumns As String() = Row.NewRow.Split(CChar(strDelimiter))


        Row.ID = strColumns(0)
        Row.NAME = strColumns(1)
        Row.DOB = strColumns(2)
        Row.NOTES = strColumns(3)
        Row.CLASSID = strColumns(4)


    End Sub
```

**Important Note: the provided code is not optimal it may need more validations or can be simpler and better but i am trying to give you the way you can think to solve this issue**

Comment: This won't work because the OP stated that the extra LF is in a column, which means to me that the reader stops reading the row at that point.  Removing the CR's from the ends would make no change at all, since it would still read extra false lines for those lines that contain LF characters in the columns.

Comment: Thx for the remark. I misunderstood the question. I will change my answer. Thx a lot

Answer (score 2):

I have no SSIS experience but as an ETL developer I have faced this many times. So my suggestions might not help you solve the problem but hopefully point you in the right direction

- If the problem field has text qualifier (single or double quote
  usually) and SSIS supports use it
- Also if there is an option
  to force SSIS to use different end of record delimiter other than LF (CRLF in this case) I'd use it (hopefully there is no CRLF in the problem field text)
- If the problem field is not the last field, you can count the number of de-limiters by reading the entire record as a single LF delimited field to
  identify and filter out the problem records (if they are only few)
  and try to stitch them back
- If possible read the file as single
  record (if SSIS has an option) and replace all LF, provided CR is
  consistent end of record delimiter from the source

Answer (score 0):

In your Flat File Connection Manager component you have a property that I forgot its name, in it you can set the row delimiter (`{CR}{LF}`, `{LF}`, `{CR}`, ...etc).

Please try to adjust this property I think it'll work.

Comment: It's not true! I used SSIS a lot in my last job, but I don't have it in my current job, so I couldn't check the property and I answered by mind.

I don't think it's a good idea to downvote when someone is trying to help and don't put a incorrect answer, by the way it's just my option.

I really don't know how is that other answer, Can you inform, please?
I think it'll be usual to have this other awnser

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this. I had a CSV file with LF as the terminator. However, the client also had CRLF in two of the columns and this was causing the "delimiter for column  is not found" error.

It took me a few days of googling solutions and trial and error, but I got it working.

In the end, I needed two script components.

In the first Script component, I had a column named Output0 string with Length of 4000. In the script (see below) I used ReadToEnd to load the data, replace the CRLF with an empty string, and then spliting into rows with the LF as the terminator.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    private StreamReader textReader;
    private string collateralFile;

public override void AcquireConnections(object Transaction)
{

    IDTSConnectionManager100 connMgr = this.Connections.Collateral;
    collateralFile = (string)connMgr.AcquireConnection(null);

}

public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();


}

public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{

    StreamReader textReader = new StreamReader(collateralFile);
    string collatFile = textReader.ReadToEnd();


    collatFile = collatFile.Replace("\r\n", " ");
    
    String[] lines = collatFile.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
    textReader.Close();


        string nextLine;



        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            if (lines[i] != null)
            {
                nextLine = lines[i];

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nextLine))
                {
                    Output0Buffer.AddRow();
                    Output0Buffer.Output0 = nextLine;

                }
            }
          }

        }
    }
```

I tried splitting it again into columns, but it returned null values, so in the second script component I created my columns and loaded the data into them in the script.

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{

String[] columns = Row.Output0.Split(',');

Row.Description = columns[0];
Row.LegalDescription = columns[1];
Row.Address1ParsedLine1 = columns[2];
Row.Address1ParsedLine2 = columns[4];
Row.Address1ParsedCityname = columns[5];
Row.Address1ParsedStatecode = columns[6];
Row.Address1ParsedPostalcode = columns[7];
}
```