# SSIS : How to Ignore LF when CRLF delimiter

Tags: ssis, newline, delimiter, lf

Our Flat File Manager from csv file had import error due to unexpected LF in some columns, even though with file delimiter CRLF.
The csv file was transfered from other Windows system with same code page (SJIS, 932) but that file was originally exported by Linux System.

Could you kindly let me know how to ignore LF as delimiter or just remove LF from big file in SSIS?

Any advice would be appreciaed again.

Comment: I use Powershell in an "Execute process Task" to edit a copy of the file by removing the embedded LF. I then process the reformatted copy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS reading LF as terminator when its set as CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164504/ssis-reading-lf-as-terminator-when-its-set-as-crlf)

Comment: Dear all, sorry for my late reply. Finally, our upstream system would handle this matter as same as the other issues. But all of your comments were so helpful with me, next time when I need to handle this kind of matter at my own system, I'll try Power Shell removing as MiguelH kindly adviced or good script task sample Hadi introduced. Thank you so much for all of your help. Sincerly, Sachiko